# Are Guild Wars 2 Gem keys region locked?

Tags: guild-wars-2, region-lock

I saw an offer online for a Gem key that you can activate with a code.

Now, it does say 'Region:EU' but I wanted to be sure and ask if I can or can not activate it even though I play on an NA server?

I 'assume' the answer is no, but hey, you never know, maybe someone tried before and it worked or just generally knows more about it.

Comment: (Sorry for so many typos in my post.)
I.... meanwhile got my answer myself.

It seems there is no region lock on them, at least not if you live in the same country as the code region.

Not sure about real cross region though.

Comment: Please post your solution as answer to the question, so others see that it has been answered. :)

Answer (score 2):

As you have already found out yourself, the key does not seem to be region locked.

To expand on this, a Guild Wars 2 account is not bound to any region. As an inhabitant of the EU, I can play on both EU or NA servers without changing anything in my account. Therefore, there is no region, as such, for the key's origin to be checked against.

Whether you input an EU or NA key, the account will be a generic account, not a region-bound account.